# Know which UI Elements are in IOS Native Apps?

Tags: iphone, ios7

im trying to add something like it is in contacts IOS app. Where you can add many phones dinamically by clicking the button "add new phone".

I want to do something similar to this and i cant found nothing.

But makes me wonder about other things i would like to do later and i also dont know how to they either.

As you would notice, im an IOS developer beginner. So, is there a way to know at least how Apple Native Apps UI are done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is always the [UIKit User Interface Catolog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857) on the Apple Developer Site.

There is also the related [View Controller Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH1-SW1) which is also useful as you'll need a place to manage these views.

Lists the available native controls and the appropriate places to use them.

Comment: Thanks, this is usefull. Any help about what im looking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The Contacts app is provided with the iOS SDK, so you can attach to its process using Xcode, and then investigate. The tip of the iceberg is this line in the debugger: `po [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow recursiveDescription]`. This will print the entire view hierarchy of the window.

This is not so simple with other software which is not found in the simulator. Apple does not allow attaching to release binaries on a real device. A solution for this is to use a jailbroken device and replace the debug daemon with a patched one to allow attaching to release binaries. After doing that, you can attach to any app and inspect its view hierarchy.